# how to change solr home data directory

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using solr 5.2.1 on ubuntu server, I have created some cores in it and added data to it.

After some time due to some error I restarted solr service using following command

```
service solr restart
```

After this command my data directory got suddenly changed from

"/opt/solr/server/solr"
to
"/var/solr/data"

on dashboard it is showing as Dsolr.solr.home=/var/solr/data

Now how can I change this home data path, what is process or command to change this path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

command to change home path

```
solr start -s /opt/solr/server/solr
```

or if you are not in bin page than also specify its full path.

```
bin/solr start -s /opt/solr/server/solr
```

Comment: and how can this configured into config files so that it is not not necessary to use this in the start command -s option?

Comment: found the answer myself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69583377/configure-solr-home-directory-instead-using-s-in-bin-solr-start-command/69584288#69584288