# Configure Solr home directory instead using -s in bin/solr start command

Tags: solr

How can I configure the solr home path?
It works for me if I using the -s option in the start command:

> bin/solr start -s /opt/solr/server/xy

But I want that solr use the home folder "/opt/solr/server/xy" also when I start solr WITHOUT the -s option like this:

> sudo service solr start

I had configure in bin/solr.in.sh -> SOLR_HOME=/opt/xy/apps/solr/server/xy but when I restart (stop and start) solr the admin panel shows me: solr.solr.home /var/solr/data - which is wrong.

I also try to change the SOLR_HOME entry in the /etc/default/solr.in.sh file  but that didn't work either

Comment: Have you seen how you configure `SOLR_HOME` in `solr.in.sh` in the reference guide: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/taking-solr-to-production.html#environment-overrides-include-file ?

Comment: I had configure in bin/solr.in.sh -> SOLR_HOME=/opt/xy/apps/solr/server/xy but when I restart (stop and start) solr the admin panel shows me: solr.solr.home /var/solr/data - which is wrong.

Comment: There is a `install_solr_service.sh` script under the `bin` folder. I wonder if you can set it up there.

Answer (score 2):

In the default file there were 2 entries that were overwritten.
It is the case that the "SOLR_HOME entry" in the "/etc/default/solr.in.sh" file has to be overwritten.

Comment: basically you can add at the end of this file : SOLR HOME="/some-path/solr/data"    and set chown solr:solr -R "/some-path/solr/data